# Center of a GeoJSON Polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, leaflet, geojson

I'm looking to reposition a JavaScript map based on [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) data. Can I calculate the center point of a [Polygon](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#polygon) from its array of `coordinates`? e.g. with:

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [
                    -9.31640625,
                    43.83452678223682
                ],
                /* etc */
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is center of polygon in your case?

Comment: Have a look on this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/248076/getting-the-center-of-a-feature-collection-in-geojson?newreg=250852bb9b474889b0357a18ad240dac